# Javascript not working after jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site for a client and a big deal to him (don't ask me why) was to have music playing the whole time and switching pages should continue the song rather than replay it. I used Jquery load to basically load each page into the content area of my index.html

**Example of page load**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#maincontent").load("home.html");
    });
</script>
```

**Page Changer**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageChanger(page){
        $("#maincontent").load();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
</script>
```

As you can see at http://file.gflam.com/MothersDayStore it works well and as it should. My issue though is I have this script loading in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.2.js"></script>
```

It runs when you first go to the site and you'll see the products at the bottom scroll, however, if you leave the page then go back to the home page they're no longer in the slide show. This is the same behavior as if I were to remove the `jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.2.js` script from the header. My guess (I'm not great at this still learning) is that because it's in the header it's only loaded on the page load so when jquery loads the page content it no longer is run?

Any help on keeping the slide show or reloading that script would be much appreciated. Also please leave comments if you need more code or more of an explanation as I hope I was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you see this code in the home.html file. Wrap that in a function. Call it in the load of the page, right after it. Then in your load of the various pages. function pageChanger(page), test for 'home.html' , if so, - then call to the function. ala.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   function initializeCarousel(){
    $('#foo4').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        auto: {
            timeoutDuration : 4000,     //  5 * auto.duration
        },
        width: '100%',
        scroll: {
            items : 4,     //  5 * auto.duration
            pauseOnHover    : true,     //  scroll.pauseOnHover
        },
        prev: '#prev2',
        next: '#next2',
        pagination: "#pager2",
        items: {
            width: 250,
            height: 'auto', //  optionally resize item-height
            visible: {
                min: 4,
                max: 4
            }
        }
    })
  }
initializeCarousel();
});




function pageChanger(page){
  $("#maincontent").load(page);
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    if(page == 'home.html'){
      initializeCarousel();
    }
}
```

I am sure there is a more succinct way of handling this. But the fact you are loading the .html, you already reinitilized it on initial page load. When you go back to 'home.html', you've already done away with that initialization. You have to re-init it.

Comment: Thanks a million that was it, I was racking my brains for a good hour or two on that one